# Issue setting up the development environment for ProjectTango developemnt Device

Tags: google-project-tango

I have a Project Tango development Kit. I am interested in working on the depth data from the sensors.
I have ADB setup on my machine. But the Eclipse android emulator doesn't detect the Tango Development tablet.

Can anyone suggest me how to set things up for the device!.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that USB debugging is enabled in order to enter ADB, go to Settings > About tablet > Build number and then press Build number seven times. Then press back and go to Developer options > USB debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your device manager (if on Windows) and look for Android Composite ADB Interface (under Android Device).

I found the driver for this at http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Right click Android Composite ADB Interface, go to the driver tab, and click update driver.  Then select Browse my computer for driver software and point it to the location where you extracted the usb driver package.

After doing this confirm that ADB can see your device by opening a command prompt, navigate your android sdk folder, and then go into a folder called platform-tools.  Then run the command "adb.exe devices". If the tango is listed there then your drivers are correctly installed and adb can see the Tango.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows 7 and it only saw the Tablet as a storage device.  I had enabled developer options in the tablet as described above, but I had missed the step on turning on USB debugging.  The moment I did that it appeared as a ADB device and I installed the Google USB driver and then I could see it and deploy onto it from Android Studio.

I previously had issues with the Peanut but if you followed the instructions for that EXACTLY it would work  You have to specify the device driver file exactly,
 not let windows chose one for you or let it tell you that its driver is better :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the driver in your device manager.

1. Click start
2. Right-click "Computer"
3. Select "Manage"
4. Select "Device Manager"
5. Find your device
6. Right-click "Update Driver Software"
7. Choose "Browse my computer"

Now search for the Android SDK you installed (on mine it is in c:\users\MyName\AppData\Local\Android\SDK) and select the sub folder Extras\Google\USBDriver