# adb command doesn't list my device

Tags: adb, android-sdk-tools, google-project-tango

On a Macbook Pro with Yosemite -
After getting through the difficulties of getting Android SDK installed, I plug in the device, but it doesn't show. The command adb devices yields "List of devices attached" with nothing following. It's there on the USB, the About This Mac System Report shows it present on the USB.

This question looks similar to [Issue setting up the development environment for ProjectTango developemnt Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592739/issue-setting-up-the-development-environment-for-projecttango-developemnt-device) but is not the same because I'm not using Eclipse.

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging on the device?

Comment: have you installed the USB drivers?

Comment: I am seeing this very frequently on my MAC. adb devices -l lists down the phones but after a few minutes it drops off.

    system_profiler SPUSBDataType

shows that those phones are still there but adb devices fails to list.

Answer (score 18):

Please ensure that USB debugging is enabled in order to enter ADB, go to Settings > About tablet > Build number and then press Build number seven times. Then press back and go to Developer options > USB debugging.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, and Paul - that was it exactly. It's step 2 in the setup instructions, which I must have jumped over too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the latest [Google USB driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html).  I was having this problem (but on Win 8) and updating the driver fixed it, I'm now getting the device in adb devices and can push content to it.

Comment: The page you link to says, "If you're developing on Mac OS X or Linux, then you **do not** need to install a USB driver." And the question specifically mentions OS X.